# Passing value to php from local storage using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, cart

I.m want to pass the values from js to php that is stored in local storage

`js`

```
let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(cartItems);

 $.ajax({
    url:"read.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {data : jsonString},
    success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
      }
   })
```

`php`

```
<?php
print_r($_POST)
?>
```

on .php im getting just "array ()"

Comment: localStorage always returns a string, you don't need to `JSON.stringify` it

Comment: but still i get just blank array()

Comment: Are you sure that you have something in localStorage? Did you check for console.log(cartItems) before ajax? What does it show?

Comment: yes, console.log(cartitems) works perfect

Comment: I just created a simple [example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/08de-k4j9) which works, not sure whats different about yours though (F9 to start it). Only thing i can think of is that your `localStorage` is empty

Comment: but everytime i try console.log(cartitems) it shows exact value from the localstorage,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63154168/getting-cart-value-to-php-from-cart-html-that-is-injected-by-js?noredirect=1#comment111691098_63154168  **here is my entire dispaly function**

Answer (score 3):

using @reyno's method with all the code in the same file called 'store_user_order.php'

```
  <?php
     if(isset($_POST["data"])) {
     print_r($_POST["data"]);
     } else {
    
   ?>
    <button>SEND</button><br/>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js">                 </script>
   <script>
     const cartItems =  localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
     const jsonString = JSON.stringify(cartItems);

    $("button").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
           url: 'store_user_order.php',
           method: 'post',
           data: {
            data: jsonString
             },
             success: function(res) {
             $('body').append(res);
              },
              error: function(err) {
              $('body').append(err);
          }
       });
      })
 </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

This should work if you have items in the localstorage

Answer (score -2):

While testing, for checking values use `method: "get"`, make sure that your test values aren't huge - you will see submitted values in the address bar.

For testing (php + MySQL) I always use this method:

```
   success ? changes() : errors_list();`
```

I don't use js, so deal with syntax yourself, please.

> on .php im getting just "array ()"

You received an empty $ _POST array - nothing was sent.
Because there was nothing to send, or there was an error sending

Comment: AFAICT this does not answer any part of the question?